# Как добавить существующее виртуальное окружение (created via bash) to PYCHARM?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, pycharm

I can't find python.exe in a virtual environment

[image]

В C:\Python_project\venv\bin
[image]

[image]

Comment: Под Windows python.exe должен быть в папке Scripts. Если вы скопировали venv с другой системы, то работать это не будет - надо устаналивать venv заново.

Comment: Использовал  bash  в win10

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: Можно in Russian полностью, а то close как in English все равно? XD